# Phonegap android failing after adding phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

There are lots of issues talking about [Phonegap push notification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). May be it's updating time to time, some working solutions for some people not work for others.

I just created a fresh phonegap project(CLI 5.1.1) and added android platform and above plugin. When trying to compile it's failing with below error

> Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+

Below is the detailed compile error

> Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "C:\Users\me\Documents\PhoneGap_Apps\hello\plat
>   forms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>
> ANDROID_HOME=F:\Softwares\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
>
> Running:
>   C:\Users\me\Documents\PhoneGap_Apps\hello\platforms\android\gradle w
>   cdvBuildDebug -b
>   C:\Users\me\Documents\PhoneGap_Apps\hello\platforms\andr
>   oid\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   >     Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+ .
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-me
>     tadata.xml
>
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/
>
>   file:/F:/Softwares/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extra
>     s/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml
>
>   file:/F:/Softwares/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extra
>     s/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml
>
>   file:/F:/Softwares/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extra
>     s/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/
>      Required by:
>          :android:unspecified
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Update you Android SDK.

The Cordova Plugin named "phonegap-plugin-push" needs "Android Support Library version 23"

Process is explain in [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push#android-behaviour)

> Compiling
>
> As of version 1.3.0 the plugin has been switched to using Gradle/Maven
>   for building. You will need to ensure that you have installed the
>   Android Support Library version 23 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it's looking for a `support-v13` version in the location of `<my_sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13`

And this happens because of my `plugin.xml` (at `my_phonegap_app/plugins/phonegap-plugin-push`) having below line

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v13:23+" />
```

But I noticed that I don't have any `23+` versions in my above sdk path and I do have a folder `22.2.0` as the latest. Inside that folder there are `support-v13-22.2.0` files.
So update the plugin.xml file so that it refers to one of existing.

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0" />
```

To be safe enough, remove `android` platform and re add it before compiling

```
phonegap platform remove android
phonegap platform add android
```

Then try compile. Now it refers for the correct, existing file and compile will get success.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2h on trying build apk with *phonegap-plugin-push* plugin I found solution.

1. In config.xml of your cordova project (in your main directory), just edit or
   add this line:

   ```
   <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
   ```
2. Then remove android platform:

   ```
   cordova platform add android
   ```
3. And add it again:

   ```
   phonegap platform add android
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar/the same problem when running cordova 6.0.0 project in Visual Studio 2015

Debugging in VS Emulator and Ripple works but not on the device (Sony Xperia Z5 Compact)
Build error output contained the error "Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+."

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error        > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+.

I checked that I had the correct SDK tools etc installed on my machine (Windows 10) but still couldn´t build debug to my device.

**My solution was** to install the adb and fastboot drivers for my phone following this guide (page 2 and 3).
http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/

install driver for adb interface
http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/2/

install driver for fastboot bootloader interface
http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/3/
!note: I have a Xperia z5 and to get it in the fastboot mode the easy way is to (instead of steps 26-28) just run the adb command "adb reboot bootloader"